# Load component script from database in Angular 9 app

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular9

On an Angular 9 project I have a component that is basically a calculator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'calculator',
  template: '<form>form elements</form>',
  styles: ['form { border: 1px solid red; }']
})

export class CalculatorComponent { 

  calculate() : number {
  }

}
```

The HTML, Styles and Calculations are all contained in this component.

I will have a lot of components such as this and I need to save them in a database.

How can I integrate and run a Component in an Angular 9 application where the component script comes from a database?

Is this possible?

Comment: doesn't sound like something that is reasonably doable... maybe explore why you've chosen this design a bit and why you feel this is the best approach

Comment: I will have about 80 calculators but each user, according to their profile, will be interested only in a few ones ... So by having the calculators on the database I could relate both tables. And the calculators are also related to the analysis being done by a User and those Analysis are also on the database ... Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: just define the calculators normally and lazy load them as needed if your concern is bundle size

Comment: This is possible with eCompileComponent and eRenderComponent.

Comment: I am facing same issue i want to load component from DB based on Demand instead of adding those in entryComponent